# Deploy NodeJS application on EC2 via launch template

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I built a simple NodeJS application and ran on an EC2 instance.
Everything works fine. I decided to create an AMI (Amazon Linux based) and a launch template to be used by a ASG.
The problem is, I cannot get the application start automatically.
I tried to add the following command through the user_data field but it doesn't work:

```
node main.js
```

Any ideas on how to automatically start this application once launched by the ASG?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would add this to the startup script of the AMI, so once the instance has started it will run the script on boot.

You may want to look at PM2 as well, it's a great tool for things like this and also makes it easy to setup each node instance in cluster mode ( assuming you have an EC2 instance with more than one core )

Some other ways of doing this, albeit not an auto scale but with DigitalOcean they offer a CASS model called 'apps' that basically pushes you app into a container from a git-repo and deploys it, you can then just spin new instances out as needed. Downside is that the bandwidth is a bit small but CND etc can help with that.